# How to fix EditText error possition in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-layout-weight

I have problem with EditText error.
error label possition is not correctly like image[image], how to fix it?

My XML Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_linear_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/register_username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <EditText
            style="@style/AppTheme.EditText.OneLine.WithBorder.Login"
            android:id="@+id/register_password"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
        <EditText
            style="@style/AppTheme.EditText.OneLine.WithBorder.Login"
            android:id="@+id/register_password_confirmation"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try it without using a custom style? and do your top 2 boxes work fine?

Comment: yes, on top 2 boxes work fine

Comment: It looks like they're keeping the empty space for an icon (the text "password" is perfectly aligned with "username" but without the icon), do you set something about drawables in the custom theme?

Comment: I think there's a mistake in drawable or coding in style. can you post also your code for AppTheme.EditText.OneLine.WithBorder.Login?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put editText in TextInputLayout like that

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
        style="@style/AppTheme.EditText.OneLine.WithBorder.Login"
        android:id="@+id/register_password"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```