# How to show Error Popup for EditText correctly

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

My question is about Android/Java.

My main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainEditText1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/mainButton1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    e.setError("SO - Please enter a correct E-Mail!!!");
                }
            });
```

My picture:
[image: Error Pop-up]

As you can see, my problem is the following: The error pop-up is larger than the width of the EditText.

But I want the error pop-up to be the same width or less than the EditText (containing several lines).

How can achieve this? How can I show the error pop-up correctly and not as my image shows?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `LinearLayout` to a `ConstraintLayout`. My guess is its adding the error message to the next available place in the `layout`. If using `LinearLayout` in `horizontal` mode it will put it to the right of the `button`.

OR

Another good answer is to wrap your `EditText` in a `TextInputLayout` and set the error of the `TextInputLayout` and not the error of the `EditText`.

I got that from here
[How to fix EditText error possition in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150030/how-to-fix-edittext-error-possition-in-linearlayout)

Although the answer has no votes i do believe its the right one.